# Laravel 8: Undefined variable: articles

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I want to show some data from my `articles` table at `index.blade.php`.

So at the `ArticleController` I added this:

```
public function home()
    {
        $articles = Article::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->get();
        return view('index');
    }
```

And then at the blade, I added this:

```
@foreach($articles as $article) 
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">{{ $articles->title }}</h2>
        <p class="card-text">{{ $articles->body }}</p>
        <a href="{{ $articles->slug }}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

But now I get this error message:

```
Undefined variable: articles (View: index.blade.php)
```

So would you mind please help me out with this error? I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not sending the articles to your index.blade.php file. you can use `compact` function call to send articles on index.blade.php file.

Comment: replace all variables {{ $articles->.... }} with `{{ $article->... }}` in your template

Comment: You are not making the call correctly. Don't call by `$articles->title` but `$article->title`

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending the articles to your index.blade.php file. you can use `compact` function call to send articles on index.blade.php file.

For Example:

```
public function home()
    {
        $articles = Article::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->get();
        return view('index');
    }
```

The above function should be:

```
public function home()
    {
        $articles = Article::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->get();
        return view('index',compact($articles));
    }
```

Comment: I added that but still gets the error

Comment: disconnect the server and clear the cache, then rerun the server. 

Edit: You can clear the cache by using ` php artisan cache:clear` to clear the application cache.

Comment: mark it as answer if it resolves your issue. Thanks